update lightweight-charts with live tick data
I have the daily chart which is loaded with historical data already, and I need to update the tick data everyday when the market opens.
When I use .update it does not update the chart as expected. I use socketio to retrieve the live tick data.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

import { socket } from './socket';

function Chart() {
    const log = console.log;
    const chartContainerRef = useRef();
    const [lastDate, setLastDate] = useState();
    const { id } = useParams();
    const apiKey = 'yfmtiz4PGwIlCalGtRjsLcrQ9rF6NAHt'
    var areaSeries = [];
    var dps = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
            width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth,
            height: 300,
            layout: {
              background: {
                type: 'solid',
                color: 'transparent'
              }
            }
        });
        chart.priceScale('right').applyOptions({
          borderVisible: false,
        })
        areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries({
          lineColor: '#2962ff',
          topColor: '#2962ff',
          bottomColor: 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
          lastPriceAnimation: true
        });
        const url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${id}?apikey=${apiKey}`
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((getData) => getData["historical"])
        .then((data) => {
            for (var i = data.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
              dps.push({
                value: data[i].close,
                time: data[i].date,
            })};
            // Getting the last date to update the live tick data on this date.
            setLastDate(dps[Object.keys(dps).pop()].time);
            areaSeries.setData(dps);
            }).catch((err) => log(err));
      
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      function getStocks(stocks) {
        if (stocks !== undefined || stocks.length !== 0) {
          console.log(stocks.data);
          stocks.data.map((element) => {
            if (element.symbol == id) {
              const tickValues = [{
                value: element.price,
                time: lastDate,
              }];
              // Getting Errors
              areaSeries?.update(tickValues[0]);
              setTickValue(tickValues[0]);
              }
            });
        };
      };
      socket.on('stocks', getStocks);
      return () => {
        socket.off('stocks', getStocks);
      };
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={chartContainerRef}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='symbol/:id' element={<Chart />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}


did you figure it out?
